# Can I leave something like a mark or bookmark in Banshee on an audio book for example?

Tags: banshee, music

I'm listening to an 11 hour audio book, it's a real pain having to find the exact spot I was last. Is there a way to mark or place a sort of bookmark to the audio track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is nothing but a normal audio file, you sure can. Go to the tools-tab (or whatever it is called in English) and select bookmarks. There you can set new bookmarks, delete old and jump to already set bookmarks. That should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't actually used Banshee, but that is an interesting feature.  I listen to a lot of audiobooks, on my ipod with an audiobook app, but with this feature I can see using a small notebook for audiobooks, also (although not so portable).  There's really no necessity to even delete old bookmarks, as the latest one is the last, and you can keep old ones for important placemarks.  Thanks for posting.